# Get source code of HTML page which is forced to load in iframe

Tags: php, html, iframe, jsoup

Usually I use `Jsoup` to get HTML source code of an HTML page. Now I want to get the source code of a special page. This page has: `if (self.location == top.location)` It means that this page must be loaded in an iframe. It can't be accessed from direct pasting the url in the browser because the conditional `if` redirects you to another page.

Is there any method in java or php to get the source code from this url?

Answer (score 1):

The code `if (self.location == top.location)` is client side JavaScript. It will only run if the HTML is parsed and the JS in it is passed to a JS engine.

It is no barrier to using any method for making an HTTP request. Just use the same technique as you use elsewhere.

Comment: Nice, I suppose Jsoup parse the HTML...so I cant use Jsoup to get source code. Can I use httpRequest on Java (Eclipse) to get this source code??